# Page Resize Causes Div's to Displace

Tags: html, css

I have a master div, two div's set side by side horizontally fit within this parent div.

```css
    .parent{
      height: 360px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    }
    .boxes {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 49.85%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    }
```

```html
  

        <div class="parent">
            
            <div class="boxes">ayy lmao</div>
            <div class="boxes">ayy lmao</div>
            
        </div>
```

`

If I set width to 50%, so each div should supposedly cover 100% of the width of the parent, it displaces the second div to drop below the first and to the right.  I set the width to 49% and it seems to work (the div's don't consume 100% of the parent, thus not making the first div bump the second down), yet when the page is resized (viewed on mobile, or page resized on Desktop) at a certain point the original issue happens again.

Is there a way to fix this issue, so that the div's can each take a certain percentage of the div, each together adding to the  entirety of the parent, and upon resize they stay within the parent div and any overflow is clipped, and do not bump down or distort?  I've tried overflow-x:auto and hidden, but it still bumps the second div below, just making the parent container scroll-able.  Overflow-y just clips the entire second div from the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between the `inline-block` elements, and add `box-sizing: border-box;`. Inline elements preserve white space, so with the white space between the elements, their combined width is > 100% if both are set to `width: 50%`. And by default, padding and border make the box model of elements grow beyond their specified width. `border-box` allows you to use padding and border while respecting the specified width of the element.

```css
.parent{
  height: 360px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
.boxes {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="parent"><div class="boxes">ayy lmao</div><div class="boxes">ayy lmao</div></div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks for this.  I find the white space between inline-elements is an odd development twitch, considering one might assume the browser would think the white space in the html source would simply be ignored by a browser,  Are there alternatives to that element, or is it simply something that must be lived with?

Comment: NP. White space isn't ignored in HTML though. Think about the space between words or the space that would appear between `<span>these</span> <span>words</span>`. That space is preserved, so if each `span` is `width: 50%;` then 50% + 50% + the space between the spans is > 100%. Does that make sense? There are other alternatives, one is to set `font-size: 0;`. Lots of others, too - as with most things in HTML/CSS, there are a dozen ways to do something.

Comment: Very interesting, perhaps I'm making assumptions based upon compile time languages, where anything the compiler doesn't need is ignored.  Clearly my assumptions about some things in HTML are off, obviously I have quite a ways to go, but best wishes, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
.parent{
      height: 360px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap
    }
    .boxes {
      display: inline-block;
      flex-basis:180px;
      height: 100px;
      background:#454545;
      border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
            
            <div class="boxes">ayy lmao</div>
            <div class="boxes">ayy lmao</div>
            
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a border. If you don't feel comfortable using Flex, you can try this:

```css
   .parent{
      height: 360px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
    }
    .boxes {
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
      width: calc(50% - 2px);
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="parent">

        <div class="boxes">ayy lmao</div>
        <div class="boxes">ayy lmao</div>

    </div>
```